# Facebook SDK blocking upload of String to Firebase

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm developing an Android app which uses Facebook Login. Login's working fine and I'm able to get back info via Facebook Graph API calls.

I'm trying upload a string to my Firebase database and the string (titled parentFirstNameFromFacebook) is the first name of the user who signed into Facebook. I'm trying to eventually upload a parent object with parentFirstNameFromFacebook in its setName() method.

```
doneCreatingNameAndPasswordFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            gettingTextFromNameAndPasswordEditTexts();


            //region creating new Parent object and setting required variables
            Parent coOpCreatingParent = new Parent();

            coOpCreatingParent.setCoopCreator(true);
            coOpCreatingParent.setNumOfHoursOwned(0);


            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "id,first_name");
            new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                            if (response != null) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();

                                    parentFirstNameFromFacebook = data.getString("first_name");

                                    SharedPreferences fBookSharedPref;
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

                                    fBookSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.FBOOK_NAME_SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    editor = fBookSharedPref.edit();
                                    editor.putString(Constants.FBOOK_NAME_SHARED_PREF, parentFirstNameFromFacebook);
                                    editor.apply();


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();



            SharedPreferences fBookSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.FBOOK_NAME_SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            fbookFirstNameForUpload = fBookSharedPref.getString(Constants.FBOOK_NAME_SHARED_PREF, null);


            coOpCreatingParent.setName(fbookFirstNameForUpload);


            getProfileImageUrlFromFBookGraph();

            coOpCreatingParent.setImageUrl(parentImageIDFromFBookGraph);


            ArrayList<Child> newChildArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            coOpCreatingParent.setChildren(newChildArrayList);


            //endregion

            //region creating new ArrayList<Parent> adding Parent object from above
            ArrayList<Parent> coOpParentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            coOpParentArrayList.add(coOpCreatingParent);
            //endregion

            getReferenceOfCoOpBeingCreated();

            //region uploading entire new Co-Op object to Firebase
            CoOp coOpObjectBeingUploaded = new CoOp(coOpKey, enteredNewCoOpPassword, enteredNewCoOpName, coOpParentArrayList);
            referenceOfCoOp.setValue(coOpObjectBeingUploaded);
            //endregion

            //region going to AddChildren Activity with Co-Op key in intent
            Intent intentForNewActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddChildrenActivity.class);
            intentForNewActivity.putExtra(Constants.CO_OP_REFERENCE_TO_CHILD_ACTIVITY_KEY, coOpKey);
            startActivity(intentForNewActivity);
            //endregion


        }
    });
```

In the Firebase screenshot below, parentsInCoOp is an ArrayList and the 0 below it is the Parent object. I'm trying to set a name and Facebook URL string as other variables for that Parent object.

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMij2.png)

Whatever I do, the name doesn't show up on Firebase! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

I also tried using Shared Preferences in case there's an issue with setting parentFirstNameFromFacebook within the Facebook call's onCompleted() method. I put parentFirstNameFromFacebook in SharedPref and then got it out to pass it through parent.setName().

Once I successfully upload the first name, then I'll do the same process for the fbook image URl string.

Anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are performing the Facebook API `GraphRequest` using the `executeAsync()` method.  The request is processed on a separate thread and the `onComplete()` response is received asynchronously. I don't use the Facebook API, but am guessing the request requires communication with the Facebook servers and will require many milliseconds to deliver a response.

The result is that these statements

```
fbookFirstNameForUpload =
     fBookSharedPref.getString(Constants.FBOOK_NAME_SHARED_PREF, null);
coOpCreatingParent.setName(fbookFirstNameForUpload);
```

execute before the statements in the callback have executed and stored the name  in preferences.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So `.setName()` runs before the Facebook response arrives. THAT means that `fbookFirstNameForUpload` is null when `.setName()` runs....which is why a name doesn't end up being added to my Firebase. I should be able to just run `setName(fbookFirstNameForUpload)` WITHIN the `onComplete()` response, right?

Comment: @langsmith: Yes, you will have to move the code that depends on the Facebook response into the callback or invoke it from within the call back.